# bootstrapping a regression with autocorrelated error

Tags: r, bootstrap, autocorrelation, regression-coefficients, heteroscedasticity

I have to verify that on two variables, $X_t$ and $Y_t$ hold the followings: $Y_t=\beta \times X_t+\varepsilon_t$ and that $var(Y_t)=\gamma \times X_t^2$. In order to give evidence / support to these hyphotheses I run a nested boostrap regression. Within each bootstrap sample I estimated $beta$ using OLS; I assumed $var(Y_t) \propto (Y_t-\hat{Y_t})^2=\hat{\varepsilon_i}$  and then estimated $\gamma$ from $\hat{\varepsilon_i}=\gamma \times X^2$ on the residuals estimated on the first equation, all within the same bootstrap cycle. Nevertheless I know that on the first regression there is still some autocorrelation of the residuals. I therefore wonder whether bootstrapping the series using block boostrap / maximum entropy boostrap would allow me to get sensible confidence interval estimates of $\beta$ and $\gamma$.